# Python how to get specific value from <li>

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the release date from the following HTML:

```html
<li class="product game_product first_product">
    <div class="product_wrap">
        <div class="basic_stat product_title">
            <a href="/game/nintendo-64/the-legend-of-zelda-ocarina-of-time">
                The Legend of Zelda: Ocarina of Time
                (N64)
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="basic_stat product_score brief_metascore">
            <div class="metascore_w small game positive">99</div>
        </div>
        <div class="more_stats condensed_stats">
            <ul class="more_stats">
                <li class="stat product_avguserscore">
                    <span class="label">User:</span>
                    <span class="data textscore textscore_outstanding">9.1</span>
                </li>
                <li class="stat release_date full_release_date">
                    <span class="label">Release Date:</span>
                    <span class="data">Nov 23, 1998</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Attempts:

```py
Dates = pageSoup.find_all("li", {"class": "stat release_date full_release_date"})
```

```
Dates = pageSoup.find_all("span", {"class": "data"})
```

I have tried getting it with `stat release_date full_release_date` and `data` but it's including the score and label elements. Is there a way to just scrape `Nov 23, 1998`?

Actual results:

```
                                               Games                            Dates
0  \n\n                            The Legend of ...  \nRelease Date:\nNov 23, 1998\n
1  \n\n                            Tony Hawk's Pr...  \nRelease Date:\nSep 20, 2000\n
```

```
                                               Games         Dates
0  \n\n                            The Legend of ...           9.1
1  \n\n                            Tony Hawk's Pr...  Nov 23, 1998
```

Expected result:

```
                                               Games         Dates
0                                  The Legend of ...  Nov 23, 1998
1                                  Tony Hawk's Pr...  Sep 20, 2000
```

Comment: It seems this is the issue: you use `find_all` on the pagesoup, and then perform a second `find_all` on the same pagesoup. Instead, you'd first want to find all `li` elements with the desired classes, and then within those `li` elements look for spans. 
Thus, the second line should read `Dates.find_all(....`

Comment: These are my different attempts at getting the value (not in the same code). Will edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way to get data from `full_release_date`:

```
Dates = pageSoup.select("li.stat.release_date.full_release_date .data")
```